# Nested functions in R

Tags: r, function, dplyr, nested

I'm trying to implement the function described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1142/simple-algorithm-for-online-outlier-detection-of-a-generic-time-series) which is used for detecting outliers in a time series object.

I'm trying to roll up the code into a single function where the time series vector, window and threshold is specified in an outer function.

Unfortunately I can't get it to work on my example, I'm receiving the following error:

> Error in zoo(do.call("c", dat), index(data)[ix], attr(data,
> "frequency")) :  “x” : attempt to define invalid zoo object

Here is the data I'm using, taken straight from the example linked above:

```
n.length <- 1150
cycle.a <- 11
cycle.b <- 365/12
amp.a <- 800
amp.b <- 8000

set.seed(17)
x <- 1:n.length
baseline <- (1/2) * amp.a * (1 + sin(x * 2*pi / cycle.a)) * rgamma(n.length, 40, scale=1/40)
peaks <- rbinom(n.length, 1,  exp(2*(-1 + sin(((1 + x/2)^(1/5) / (1 + n.length/2)^(1/5))*x * 2*pi / cycle.b))*cycle.b))
y <- peaks * rgamma(n.length, 20, scale=amp.b/20) + baseline
```

Here is my rolled up function:

```
mad_function <- function(vec, threshold, window){
  
  upper_thresh <- function(vec) {
    
    # CALCULATE THE MEDIAN OF THE WINDOW
    m <- median(vec)
    
    # CALCULATE THE MEDIAN ABSOLUTE DEVIATION
    median(vec) + threshold * median(abs(vec - m))
    
    return(upper_thresh)
  }
  
  # CALCULATE THE MEAN ABSOLUTE DEVIATIONS FOR EACH ROLLING WINDOW
  mads <- rollapply(zoo(vec), window, upper_thresh, align = "right")
  
  # CONCATENATE THE FIRST VALUE OF THE MADs VECTOR TO THE MADs RESULT ABOVE DUE TO THE ROLLING WINDOW EFFECT
  mads <- c(rep(mads[1], window - 1), mads)
  
  # IDENTIFY IF POINTS ARE OUTLIERS OR INLIERS
  outliers <- vec > mads
  
  return(outliers)
  
}
```

I'm trying to run this function on the y variable, but this is where I get the error:

```
mad_function(vec = y, threshold = 5, window = 30)
```

Based on the error I'm guessing the rollapply section has no 'visibility' of 'vec' but I'm not sure how to resolve the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code is returning the `upper_thresh` function itself rather than the value it computes.  Remove the `return` statement from `upper_thresh`.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck thanks so much, this solved my problem, cheers for the help.